# Update column in DESC order until a value appears

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to update values of a NULL column in descending order until a value appears?

So basically

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = "val" WHERE myColumn IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC 
(Until myColumn has a non-NULL value, then stop updating).
```

Comment: You have WHERE condition, where you limit update query only to records with myColumn IS NULL, you don't need ORDER BY here

Comment: I want to stop ALL updates once the single condition of a value existing has been met. In this case from a DESC order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = "val"
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM myTable
            WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the value isn't `NULL`, the `WHERE` condition is FALSE and this record stays untouched.

No other condition (you put that into bracket below) isn't needed in this case.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, I don't want to continue doing a table search once a single condition has been met.